# How to put delay in FLEX code?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, delay

I want code for keeping 1 second delay in Flex.

i.e. i want to call some function every second delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setInterval()` function for that.

For more information check out the [livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html).

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() is what you're looking for